# How does max-width property make images responsive?

Tags: css

I have an image something like below.

```
<img src="file.jpg" />
```

Below is the css code

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Can anyone explain me on how does this `css` code make the images responsive, I mean scale it perfectly. I want to know the working behind this `css` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your parent width is smaller than width of image, image width will take 100% of parent width.
If parent width is bigger than image width, image width will stay original.
Same with `max-height`. Also `min-width`/`min-height` will ensure that width/height will not be smaller than specified.
`height: auto;` will preserve aspect ratio for image. If you set both `max-height` and `max-width` or set height to specific size than image will be stretched

Answer (score 2):

When you apply `max-width:100%;` to any element then that perticular element could have maximum 100% width of its parent, thus it can give you gaurantee that child will never go out of parent's bounds.

Thus if parent has suffitient width then child is shown in it's original size, otherwise it's width is matched to the parent. Thus it make our layout responsive.

Here is example : http://jsfiddle.net/xxn2hfuL/